# Erasing Must Not Happen

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt

I asked a similar question here:
[Leaving a trace while painting on a transparent JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20305653/leaving-a-trace-while-painting-on-a-transparent-jpanel)

One person did try to help me, however I think I wasn't able to make myself clear, so he misunderstood what I wanted.

I want to know how I can stop repaint() from erasing my panel. If I delete the setOpaque(false); statement, it seems to stop the erasing- however, I don't get the background color.

Comment: No.  You need to redraw everything whenever the panel is painted.  The fact that you don't like it doesn't make the answer to your previous question any less true.

Comment: -1, No, I understood and told you that is not the way Swing works. There are ways to fudge it, but as soon as Swing determines the component needs to be repainted you will lose everything. For example when the frame is resized.

Comment: how does it stop erasing if I comment out setOpaque(false)?

Comment: @user3015246 It doesn't, this is actually a bad paint side effect

Comment: I asked a  question 2 minutes ago, but I got an answer 3 minutes ago? Can SLaks go back in time? Oh sorry, my mistake!

Comment: Because you are breaking a breaking a fundamental painting rule by not invoking super.paintComponent(). Anyway try resizing the frame and see what happens. `Time for you to start accepting answers`. I'm tired of you asking all these questions without accepting answer from any of your previous questions.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I want to be the JVM. How does Swing work then? Why does it have such a side effect?

Comment: @Camickr: I tried resizing. It does seem to qwork. What do you mean?

Comment: @user3015246 Basically, when the component is transparent, Swing will paint the components below yours, which is updating the `Graphics` context.  When it's opaque, you are begin given the same `Graphics` context which was used previously, this is a side effect and should not be relied upon.  What will happen, when you add other components into the mix, is you will see what ever they painted to the `Graphics` context before you painted on you component.  This why you MUST call `super.paintComponent`

Comment: @Camickr: You are the only person who gave -1 though! You did it 2 or 3 times. I understand that I am new and may not understand all the rules yet, but I am curious, I want to learn, and I thought this place is supposed to be helpful?

Comment: @madProgrammer: OK, it is kind of making sense. Can I save the shape I am drawing with each timer beat and then merge them all?

Comment: Based on your code, I don't see the point, as the rectangle will grow beyond the size of the previous shape that you painted last, seen as you're filling it.  Follow camickr's advice, update the x/y values outside of the `paintComponent` method, as paint might be called for any number of reasons...

Comment: @user3015246, `You could have just informed me this properly` - I did inform you properly. I informed you in your last question. I then answered your question in good faith assuming that you would listen to my suggestion and go back to accept answer from your previous questions. `I accepted one answer` - which is NOT good enough. You should revisit all your old answers. If you had done this the first time it was suggested, there would have been no reason to nag you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Painting in Swing is a destructive process.  The `Graphics` context used by you component to paint itself is a shared resource, that is, the components painted before your component and after it will use the same graphics context.

This means, if you don't clear it, you will see what ever was painted before you...

It is a requirement of the framework that you clear the `Graphics` context before you start you painting...

To this end, it is expected that when `paintComponent` is called, you will completely redraw what ever it is you need repainted.

Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

You need to stop fighting the process and start learning to work with it - your life will be much simpler if you do ;)

**Updated with an example of a possible basic approach**

Basically, this simply creates a random point some where within the confines of the component, adds that point to a `List` and request that the component be repainted.  The `paintComponent` method simply loops through this list a paints the points, after it calls `super.paintComponent` to prepare the `Graphics` context for painting...

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class AutoPaint {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AutoPaint();
    }

    public AutoPaint() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>(25);

        public TestPane() {
            Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    points.add(new Point(random(getWidth()), random(getHeight())));
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            for (Point p : points) {
                g2d.drawLine(p.x, p.y, p.x, p.y);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        protected int random(int range) {
            return (int)Math.round(Math.random() * range);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: OK, thanks. I understand. But I should be able save what I paint each time, say, with an ArrayList. Can't I?

Comment: That's one approach, yes...